# ora-00979 not a GROUP BY expression help spool

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, ora-00979

```
SET colsep '|'
SET echo OFF
SET feedback OFF
SET linesize 1000
SET pagesize 0
SET sqlprompt ''
SET trimspool ON
SET headsep OFF

spool monitor.csv

SELECT error_id, '|', error_desc, '|', b.control_by
  FROM error a, component_info b
 WHERE a.error_id IN (
         SELECT error_id FROM component_thresh JOIN component_info USING (component_id))
 GROUP BY b.control_by
 ORDER BY a.error_desc
/
```

I need to group by a  column in a different table then order it by error_desc then spool out results.

Edit: Ah! I needed to order by both.

Comment: When you use `GROUP BY` in Oracle (and majority of other SQL implementations) in your `SELECT` clause you can have only fields that are used for grouping and/or aggregated values (such as `COUNT`, `MIN`, `SUM`, etc.)

Comment: why do you want to group by?

Comment: @user2992757 . . . Perhaps the client wants `order by`, so rows with the same `control_by` will appear together.

Comment: "Grouped by control_by and in abc order within the grouping."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you want to order all the rows with the same `control_by` together, to be able to browse them. What `GROUP BY` attempts to do is put everything into one row, and it doesn't seem like this is what you want.

You can use ORDER BY clause instead of GROUP BY. This will put all the rows with the same `control_by` to appear together. Also, you can `GROUP BY b.control_by, a.error_id`; and get the same result. The best option is to use `ORDER BY control_by, error_desc`.

```
select error_id, '|', error_desc, '|', b.control_by from 
  error a, component_info b where 
  a.error_id in (
    select error_id
    from component_thresh
    join component_info using(component_id)
    )
 order by b.control_by, a.error_desc;
/
```

This should do the trick for your client.